# Using Emacs.app when building from source (Mac OS)

Tags: osx, build

I've built Emacs from source on MacOS (12.4, M1) and it works when I execute the binary from `/usr/local/bin/emacs`, but I can't open Emacs from Emacs.app.

For example:

```
mv ~/emacs/nextstep/Emacs.app /Applications/Emacs.app
```

I then try to open Emacs.app from my Applications folder, but it silently fails.

Here's how I'm building Emacs from source:

```
$ ./autogen.sh

$ ./configure --with-native-compilation \
              --with-ns \
              --disable-silent-rules \
              --disable-ns-self-contained

$ make

$ make install
```

I can open emacs no problem when I use the installed binary in `/usr/local/bin`:

```
$ emacs & # good to go!
```

Here's what I get when trying to run the Emacs binary within Emacs.app:

```
$ /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs

Error using execdir /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/:
emacs: dlopen(/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/../native-lisp/29.0.50-6a95966f/preloaded/window-0d1b8b93-33d07edc.eln, 0x0001): tried: '/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/../native-lisp/29.0.50-6a95966f/preloaded/window-0d1b8b93-33d07edc.eln' (no such file)
```

**edit**

I found perhaps a related issue: [homebrew-emacs-plus#392](https://github.com/d12frosted/homebrew-emacs-plus/issues/392) and it's [associated fix](https://github.com/d12frosted/homebrew-emacs-plus/commit/39fbf046b2cf25f8f39a9a7508faeab789b1d158). Perhaps the problem is related to the `emacs/native-lisp` directory not being present in the Emacs.app package.

I tried to resolve by simply moving the `native-lisp/` directory into my Emacs.app package:

```
$ mv ~/emacs/nextstep/Emacs.app /Applications/Emacs.app
$ mv ~/emacs/native-lisp/ /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/
```

This appeared to fix the issue, in that I was able to use Emacs.app and launch the program. However, after launching the program this way there are a suite of warnings that show up related to native compilation:

```
libgccjit.so: error: error invoking gcc driver
```

I think simply moving the native-lisp/ folder into the app package was probably not sufficient.

Comment: Try at the command line: `open /Applications/Emacs.app` ; it may print an error that could help figure this out.

Comment: No additional output from `open ...`, but I did try `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs` to run the binary included within the App folder and got "Error using execdir". I added the full output to the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what ended up resolving this problem for me:

1. Remove `--disable-ns-self-contained` from the configure script, to ensure that all build artifacts are copied into the Emacs.app package.

```
./configure --with-native-compilation \
            --with-ns \
            --disable-silent-rules
```

2. Re-run the Emacs build.
3. Symlink `nextstep/Emacs.app` instead of moving it (though I think since self-contained is enabled, you can really just move this to `Applications` so this may be unnecessary).
4. Add `emacs/src/` and `emacs/lib-src` to your PATH so you can still run emacs via CLI.

Answer (score 1):

Do not move the Emacs.app to Applications folder; instead use a symlink:
`ln -s /opt/homebrew/opt/emacs-plus@28/Emacs.app /Applications` - (modify this one for your path). Note `brew` also compile from sources and install on your computer. It uses several patches to finalise the installation.

Edit:
You can drag and drop it on doc, no need to write symlink.
Edit 2:
I added the following lines in my `.zshrc`

```sh
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/emacs-plus@28/28.2/bin:$PATH"
alias ec="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/emacs-plus@28/28.2/bin/emacsclient"
alias te="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/emacs-plus@28/28.2/bin/emacs -nw"
```

Comment: This works if I don't pass the `--disable-ns-self-contained` flag, but continues to fail with that flag present. Maybe I just need to stop passing that flag if I want to use Emacs.app, and add emacs/src/ and emacs/lib-src/ to my PATH so I have access to emacs/emacscilent from the command line?

Comment: See the Edit #2.

Comment: Even with this strategy, the self-contained Emacs.app continues to have issues. It launches, but emits a ton of `"libgccjit.so: error: error invoking gcc driver"` warnings into my Messages buffer. Meanwhile, `src/emacs` works totally fine.

I have libgccjit installed via brew, so I imagine there's something going on with the Emacs.app paths.